# npm command not sending authorization token in request - unable to authenticate

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm having this problem when I issue an npm command I get a message that it is unable to authenticate with the npm registry (hosted in Azure DevOps) and I suspect that it might be because it is not generating an authorization header and sending it along with the request.

For example, when I issue these commands: `npm ping` or `npm install`, it gives this complaint.

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, your authentication token seems to be invalid.
npm ERR! To correct this please trying logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\blah\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-15T06_30_45_484Z-debug.log
```

I have a different npm registry (hosted under a different Azure DevOps instance) that works when I issue these commands and upon looking at the requests under Fiddler, I noticed that the working request has the authorization header contain the username and password to access the registry, however, the non-working request (to the non-working registry) does not have it.

Besides the registry url,username, and password in the npmrc file, they are pretty much the same as shown here:

```
registry=https://devops.blah/npm/registry/
always-auth=true
strict-ssl=false
; Treat this auth token like a password. Do not share it with anyone, including Microsoft support. This token expires on or before 02/03/2020.
; begin auth token
//devops.blah/npm/registry/:username=blah
//devops.blah/npm/registry/:_password=blahpassword
//devops.blah/npm/registry/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
//devops.blah/npm/:username=blah
//devops.blah/npm/:_password=blahpassword
//devops.blah/npm/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
; end auth token
```

The npm command was issued on the same machine and in the same command prompt session (I switch to the relevant npmrc profile when I do so).

What could cause the npm command to not include the Authorization Header in its request to the non-working registry?